# Can I prevent Grunt from passing if Compass Gem is not installed?

Tags: javascript, build, rubygems, compass-sass, gruntjs

We have a Gruntfile that specifies our Grunt tasks for building Javascript in different environments.

It also includes tasks for building SCSS files, which depend on Compass. When being triggered, Bundler tries to execute Compass and fails if it is not installed.

The Grunt tasks do not seem to be aware of that error, as they simply finish saying "Done, without errors."

Is there any way to make Grunt notice the absence of Compass on the system?
Otherwise, every Build that breaks on this error, but looks as if it passed from outside, will be hard to debug for us.

```
Running "compass:production" (compass) task
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:296:in `resolve': Could not find gem 'compass (>= 0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine. (Bundler::GemNotFound)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:168:in `start'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:129:in `block in resolve'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:128:in `catch'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:128:in `resolve'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:179:in `resolve'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:114:in `specs'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:159:in `specs_for'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:148:in `requested_specs'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/environment.rb:18:in `requested_specs'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in `setup'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `setup'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/setup.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'

[...]

Done, without errors.
```

Comment: I agree that the compass task should throw an error in that case, but if you can't guarantee that the components are installed on your build server, you may want to use something like Chef http://www.opscode.com/chef/ to automate build server creation. This way you don't have to worry about someone forgetting to install ruby + compass when creating your build server.

Comment: Would you mind posting the Gruntfile with the compass config?

Comment: @MikeP Thanks, we'll take that into consideration.

Comment: @pezzi http://pastebin.com/EF2TPG6M - should work, but untested, as I had to cut some content from the original Gruntfile.

Comment: Have you got a Gemfile in your project as well? something simple as:

`source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'compass'
`

Comment: Yes, it looks exactly like that.